# spark : what happens for data cached in container when it is dead?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

I have a cluster of 9 nodes, scalable to 19 nodes.
I persisted dataframe in memory, the size of data in memory was 61.9 Gb.
Then, for some problems in configurations, Yarn started loosing connection with some nodes (It wasn't an OutOfMemory problem).

After every node dead, a new one was created.

So i noticed that the size of memory of cached dataframe kept increasing with every node created, it reached 110 Gb !

I thought that when a container is dead, the data that it was caching in memory will be splitted on other containers, or will all be moved to a new container, and thus, the size of memory remains the same.

But the size of data in memory keeps increasing.

So i don't really understand what happens to cached data when its container is dead ?

And why it keeps increasing ?

Thank you very much !